# Add lines at the end of file

Tags: c, file, logging

I would like to add logs at the end of a file for each event, and create a new one when its size up to 255 Mo.

For example, the current file could be /var/log/foo.2:

```
/var/log/foo.0.log (full log file)
/var/log/foo.1.log (full log file)
/var/log/foo.2.log
```

Have you got an idea of C source to do so?

Thank you

Comment: What code do you have in place now?  This is not "please do my homework for me.com"  What problems are you having with the code you have written so far?

Comment: Uh, this doesn't sound very homework-y to me.

Comment: agreed, but before you get down voted into oblivion... 
just google "c file manipulation"
an read, if you know any C at all you should be able to understand this, otherwise just ask you Prof. for help

Comment: @GMan: Since this is a built-in feature of most logging libraries, there aren't many reasons to re-invent it.  Homework is the biggest reason.

Comment: Actually the right raison is that: I am a big noob in C. So even if this could be simple for you, it was difficult for me and I am happy to read every of your comments and answers, really. In this regard, I note that this is not a duty but a personal task. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When opening the file with

```
File *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
```

choose "a" as mode. Which will open or create a text file for writing at the end of file.

Comment: Afaik it should say "FILE *fopen(...)".

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have the functionality, look at [log4c](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/).

If you want to know how that works, you can look at its code as well.

If you need specially tailored code for your application...

Basically you need to use `fopen` with the `"a"` option, where a stands for append.

To determine size of a file, use `ftell` or another platform specific function because there is no file size information method in the C standard as far as I can remember. Or you go the long way and just read all the bytes from the file and count them...

Answer (score 0):

Basic c file code: http://c-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/c_tutorial_file_handling_commands